# maximum connections for your account has been reached error with System.Net.FtpClient library

Tags: c#, ftp

I use this library for connecting to remote FTP server and downloading stock (csv) files: https://netftp.codeplex.com/

I have wrapped the connection, download & disconnection sequence in a wrapper like this:

```
class FTPConnection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Private class objects.
    /// </summary>
    private string ftpHost;
    private string ftpUser;
    private string ftpPass;
    private string ftpDocRoot;
    private int ftpPort;
    private int ftpTimeout;
    private FtpClient ftpClient;

    /// <summary>
    /// Class constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ftpHost"></param>
    /// <param name="ftpPort"></param>
    /// <param name="ftpUser"></param>
    /// <param name="ftpPass"></param>
    /// <param name="ftpDocRoot"></param>
    /// <param name="ftpTimeout"></pparam>
    public FTPConnection(string ftpHost, int ftpPort, string ftpUser, string ftpPass, string ftpDocRoot, int ftpTimeout = 30)
    {
        // Remember settings
        this.ftpHost = ftpHost;
        this.ftpPort = ftpPort;
        this.ftpUser = ftpUser;
        this.ftpPass = ftpPass;
        this.ftpDocRoot = ftpDocRoot;
        this.ftpTimeout = ftpTimeout;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to test connection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Test()
    {
        // Connect to ftp server
        Connect();

        // Check if connected
        bool isConnected = ftpClient.IsConnected;

        // Disconnect
        Disconnect();

        // Finished
        return isConnected;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to download stock file from ftp server.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stockFileDir"></param>
    /// <param name="supplierId"></param>
    /// <param name="stockFileNamePattern"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string DownloadStockFile(string stockFileDir, int supplierId, string stockFileNamePattern)
    {
        // Init
        string localFilePath = "";

        // Connect to ftp server
        Connect();

        // Load remote ftp server files
        foreach (FtpListItem ftpListItem in ftpClient.GetListing(stockFileDir, FtpListOption.Modify | FtpListOption.Size))
        {
            if (ftpListItem.Type == FtpFileSystemObjectType.File && ftpListItem.Name.Contains(stockFileNamePattern))
            {
                localFilePath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}_{2}", Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), supplierId, ftpListItem.Name);
                if (File.Exists(localFilePath)) File.Delete(localFilePath);
                using (var ftpStream = ftpClient.OpenRead(ftpListItem.FullName))
                using (var fileStream = File.Create(localFilePath, (int)ftpStream.Length))
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
                    int count;
                    while ((count = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Disconnect
        Disconnect();

        // Finished
        return localFilePath;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to connect to ftp server.
    /// </summary>
    private void Connect()
    {
        // Connect to ftp server
        if (null == ftpClient || !ftpClient.IsConnected)
        {
            ftpClient = new FtpClient();
            ftpClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            ftpClient.Host = ftpHost;
            ftpClient.Port = ftpPort;
            ftpClient.ConnectTimeout = 1000 * ftpTimeout;
            ftpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPass);
            ftpClient.Connect();
            ftpClient.SetWorkingDirectory(ftpDocRoot);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to disconnect from ftp server.
    /// </summary>
    private void Disconnect()
    {
        try
        {
            ftpClient.Disconnect();
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            if (null != ftpClient)
                ftpClient.Dispose();
            ftpClient = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is used in a "Sync" application, which polls the ftp server and grabs the first matching file by file name pattern.

This is how I use the wrapper:

```
// Init
string stockFilePath = string.Empty;

// Connect to ftp server and download the stock file
FTPConnection ftpConnection = null;
try
{
    // Init connection
    ftpConnection = new FTPConnection
    (
        supplierConfig.FTPHost,
        supplierConfig.FTPPort,
        supplierConfig.FTPUser,
        supplierConfig.FTPPass,
        supplierConfig.FTPDir
    );

    // Download stock file
    stockFilePath = ftpConnection.DownloadStockFile(supplierConfig.FTPDir, supplierConfig.PLSupplierAccountID, supplierConfig.StockFileNamePattern);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Re throw exception
    throw new Exception("Failed to download stock file - " + ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    // Clean-up
    ftpConnection = null;
}
```

When the code executes, it works exactly as intended. Grabs the file and stores it and returns the full path to local file.

However, when the code executes again (after a set interval), I keep getting this error:

> The maximum connections for your account has been reached (4).

However, you can see in my wrapper that I am closing the ftp connection and disposing the ftp client object and cleaning up.

Any idea how I am reaching the maximum connections for ftp account of `4`?

If I were to close the app and open it, it starts working again fine. Is this an issue with the remote ftp server? It looks like it is only able to connect once.

Comment: `ftpConnection = null;` not close your conn, you have to call `Disconnect()`

Comment: You could use CMD with "netstat -a" to check how many connections are open. "netstat /?" if you want to see the options for that command.

Comment: @Sakura Good point! I totally missed that. I saw "disposing" and made a bad assumption that using() was being used.

Comment: Take a look at the code again. The `ftpConnection` object is an instance of the wrapper class (not the actual ftp client from `System.Data.FtpClient`). Within the wrapper, on the `DownloadStockFile` method, I call the private `Connect` method to init the connection and when I am done with the task, I call `Disconnect` which calls the `ftpClient.Disconnect()` and then disposes the object.

Comment: Do you found the true reason cause the error yet?

Comment: No not yet. I've downloaded their example to see how the library was supposed to be used and re-wrote my wrapper to use the `using` method like this: http://pastebin.com/G6tJ586a - I am still getting the same error. This is the official sample for `GetListing` http://pastebin.com/B3E0U6w3 and `OpenRead` http://pastebin.com/Q7TDs92W

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrap the client in a using block to see if disposing the whole object allows you to connect repeatedly:

```
using (FtpClient conn = new FtpClient()) {
     FtpReply reply;

     conn.Host = "localhost";
     conn.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftptest", "ftptest");

     if (!(reply = conn.Execute("SITE CHMOD 640 FOO.TXT")).Success) {
         throw new FtpCommandException(reply);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ftpConnection = null;` not close your conn, you have to call `ftpConnection.Disconnect()`

Comment: @Latheesan Do you realize if `DownloadStockFile` fail/cause exception, the `Disconnect()` function inside int will not be executed?

Comment: I have only shown a small portion of my code. When I call `DownloadStockFile`, I wrap it in try/catch and I have not got any exceptions thrown during testing.

Comment: @Latheesan Ok. I see you have `try { DownloadStockFile... }` but you dont use `DownloadStockFile() { try { ... } }` *(try block inside DownloadStockFile function)*. Good news it don't have any exeption. But if it have, even you wrap it inside try-catch-finally like your code above, ftpConnection will not properly dispose.

Comment: See my updated reply above - http://pastebin.com/G6tJ586a (I re-wrote the library as per official documentation and it's still giving me the same issue).

Comment: my country block pastebin. anyway, I don't want to download whole a project, learn it myself to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by browsing the available options on the `System.Data.FtpClient` to see if it had any methods/settings for `KeepAlive` / `MaxConnection` etc.... and I came across this option:

## EnableThreadSafeDataConnections

Here's what this option does:

> When this value is set to true (default) the control connection is cloned
>   and a new connection the server is established for the data channel operation.
>   This is a thread safe approach to make asynchronous operations on a single
>   control connection transparent to the developer.

So, I have set this to `false` (as I am not using the `async` method) like this:

> conn.EnableThreadSafeDataConnections = false;

And my problem is solved. Basically what was happening is, this library was keeping a connection open, each time I disconnect (up-to 4 of them) like some sort of connection pool. Setting this to false prevented it from doing that.

Here's the final working version of my code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Method to download stock file from ftp server.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="stockFileDir"></param>
/// <param name="supplierId"></param>
/// <param name="stockFileNamePattern"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public string DownloadStockFile(string stockFileDir, int supplierId, string stockFileNamePattern)
{
    // Init
    string localFilePath = "";

    // Load remote ftp server file
    using (FtpClient conn = new FtpClient())
    {
        // Set connection details
        conn.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        conn.Host = ftpHost;
        conn.Port = ftpPort;
        conn.ConnectTimeout = 1000 * ftpTimeout;
        conn.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPass);
        conn.EnableThreadSafeDataConnections = false;

        // Get file listng
        foreach (FtpListItem ftpListItem in conn.GetListing(stockFileDir, FtpListOption.Modify | FtpListOption.Size))
        {
            // Proceed if this is a file
            if (ftpListItem.Type == FtpFileSystemObjectType.File && ftpListItem.Name.Contains(stockFileNamePattern))
            {
                // Download file
                localFilePath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}_{2}", Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), supplierId, ftpListItem.Name);
                if (File.Exists(localFilePath)) File.Delete(localFilePath);
                using (var ftpStream = conn.OpenRead(ftpListItem.FullName))
                using (var fileStream = File.Create(localFilePath, (int)ftpStream.Length))
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
                    int count;
                    while ((count = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }

                    // Stop further processing
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Disconnect
        conn.Disconnect();
    }

    // Finished
    return localFilePath;
}
```

Hope this helps somebody.